# How to customize amount of columns in Joomla megamenu?

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, menu, helix3

My website has a mega menu dropdown in the main menu which shows up nicely, but the problem is that I had to choose the design for six columns to be able to implement my five desired columns in the megamenu dropdown (options for 4 and 6 columns, but not for 5).

Anyone knows how to set the amount of columns in my megamenu to 5 ? My template is helix ultimate.

Another solution would be to center my 5 columns into the body of the dropdown menu initially built with 6 columns, that wouldn't bother me. Anyone ?

Cheers!

Comment: That sounds like a question that would be best answered by the support for Helix or their community forum board. And if you are able to find a solution don't forget to come back here and update this question with an answer for the next person.

Comment: yeh but the problem is that they only provide support in their community of you pay for registering, at least like 40 bucks, it's ridiculous. So I'm defo not gonna support that way of resolving problems.

Answer (score 1):

Helix3 is based on Bootstrap 4, But all `col` classes for megamenu have prefix `col-sm`

Think the easiest method is to add custom class name `.col5` to your megamenu and split `row` into 6 columns.

Then you can add this CSS:

```
.sp-has-child.col5 .col-sm-2 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.sp-has-child.col5 .col-sm-2:last-child {
  display: none
}
```

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour] and browse our help pages to familiarise yourself with the subtle nuances between SO and here.